# Install ubuntu as a dual boot system in mac air

Tags: dual-boot, mac, refit

http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-in-macbook-air

This is what I followed to install ubuntu as a dual system for my mac air.

I have finished installing ubuntu in my mac and I can see the icon in the interface of rEFIt.

But when I selected it and typed enter, I just got a black screen.

As this article said, I need to install GPT fdisk and build a hybrid boot menu.

So I install the GPT fdisk in the OS X.
but for the hybrid boot menu, I really don't understand how to build it even if there is another post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1810275&page=19&p=11215214#post11215214

Can any one help me to build a hybird boot menu?

Comment: Try removing 'quiet' from the boot parameters to see if the blank screen is graphic driver related.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

- rEFIt has been abandoned for four years. Two years ago, I forked it as [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which has significant improvements, particularly with respect to booting Linux. You're better off using rEFInd than rEFIt.
- The instructions you followed had you do an installation in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. IMO, this should be done only as a last resort; instead, you should attempt to boot Linux in EFI mode. This is more easily done with rEFInd than with rEFIt. I've written [a page on how to do this,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) but it's outdated and uses a very old 32-bit Mac as a model. Nonetheless, if you follow the instructions under "Fixing the Installation," they should be mostly applicable.
- With an EFI-mode boot of Linux, a hybrid MBR becomes unnecessary and even undesirable, so don't bother trying to muck with one.
- Unfortunately, Macs vary an awful lot among themselves. Some of them boot and work fine in EFI mode. Others are incredibly uncooperative and must be booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode to work correctly. Thus, I can't make any promises about what will work for you.

Comment: thx a lot ur article is useful for me